# A formula for the foot of perpendicular

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I found the following formula  using derivatives but I guess there should be a geometric verification of that.

If the parametric form of a line in $R^2$ or $R^3$ is  $$X=P+t\vec{V}$$ then the parameter value for the foot of perpendicular from the point $A$ to the line is given by $$ t=\frac {\vec{PA}.\vec{V}}{\vec{V}.\vec{V}}$$

Question :

Can one prove it without using derivative?

Comment: That is the scalar (perpendicular) projection of the vector $\;\vec{PA}\;$ on the line. That's just vector geometry.

Comment: Good comment,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the triangle, you need it to be pythagorean for the angle between $A-(P+tV)$  and the line to be square. So you need 
$$
\|A-(P+tV)\|^2+\|tV\|^2=\|AP\|^2.
$$
That is, as $A-(P+tV)=(A-P)+tV=AP+tV$,
$$
\|AP\|^2+t^2\|V\|^2-2\,AP\cdot(tV)=\|AP\|^2.
$$
Solving for $t$ (the solution $t=0$ doesn't count since it gives a degenerate triangle),
$$
t=\frac{AP\cdot V}{V\cdot V}.
$$